# How can I run SELECT DISTINCT for any column in CQLSH?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Every time I try to run `SELECT DISTINCT %column_name from %table_name` I receive

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="SELECT DISTINCT queries must only request partition key columns and/or static columns (not specified %column_name)"
```

Comment: Good question, and the answer is that the same as most other query questions:  If you want to be able to serve a particular query, then your table must be designed to support it.

Comment: Check the docs: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlSelect.html#cqlSelect__distinct

Answer (score 2):

You can run `SELECT DISTINCT` only on your `partition key` column. For example, if your schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE artist (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    band_name text,
    name text,
    role text
);
```

Then query will be:

`SELECT DISTINCT id FROM artist;`